# HTML & CSS : How Do I Center DIVs for Responsive Design?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

So I have a very basic question. I am trying to move my left most menu and my content div to the dead center leaving white on either side.

But I have tried everything to but with no luck they just won't move

I have made a JSfiddle of my code : https://jsfiddle.net/7jsxL7km/

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-2 col-m-2 nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">Link2</a></li>
            <li><a href="product.html">Link3</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Link4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-m-9 content">
        <h1>This is a Header</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in ex augue. Integer bibendum rutrum elit sed fermentum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse ut ipsum eros. Vestibulum vel est velit. Cras imperdiet metus et hendrerit aliquet. In vel interdum tellus, ac porta enim. Nunc nec turpis mauris. Fusce finibus vel ante id suscipit. Fusce vel sem sit amet nisi aliquam placerat. Fusce eu est porta, pharetra felis et, consectetur libero. Vestibulum a varius nisl. Vestibulum consequat feugiat leo, et sollicitudin justo sagittis eget. Fusce maximus turpis vitae leo suscipit, quis varius massa fermentum. Morbi pharetra elit ut ante tempus imperdiet.

        Phasellus interdum felis justo, sit amet sollicitudin lacus dignissim et. Fusce aliquam, magna ac viverra tempus, enim lorem semper ipsum, at scelerisque risus dolor eget ligula. Donec semper nisl nec erat mollis blandit. Nullam turpis urna, sollicitudin maximus felis id, venenatis tincidunt eros. Sed id nibh at sapien mollis volutpat et ac quam. Sed eleifend velit quis commodo sodales. Suspendisse viverra ullamcorper massa vehicula luctus. Duis ut enim diam. Nunc ut rutrum ipsum. Nunc fringilla odio leo. Nulla nec enim nisl. Nulla in quam blandit, elementum augue sed, lobortis ligula. Fusce accumsan vel ipsum ut aliquet. Donec tempus vehicula velit, finibus laoreet justo ultricies sit amet.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
    <p>Footer Section</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
    /*background-image: url("../Images/WoodenBackground.jpg");*/
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center  
}

.row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}


/*Floats All Elements to the Left*/
[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
}

/* For mobile phones: */
[class*="col-"] {
    width: 100%;
}


.nav ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav li{
    padding: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    margin-right:7px;
    background-color: grey;
    color: Black;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: Black;
}

.nav li:hover{
    background-color: grey;
}

.nav li:active{
    background-color: grey;
}

.content{
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    background-color: grey;
    color: Black;
    text-align: center;
}

.footer {
    background-color: grey;
    color: Black;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 15px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    /* For tablets: */
    .col-m-1 {width: 8.33%;}
    .col-m-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-m-3 {width: 25%;}
    .col-m-4 {width: 33.33%;}
    .col-m-5 {width: 41.66%;}
    .col-m-6 {width: 50%;}
    .col-m-7 {width: 58.33%;}
    .col-m-8 {width: 66.66%;}
    .col-m-9 {width: 75%;}
    .col-m-10 {width: 83.33%;}
    .col-m-11 {width: 91.66%;}
    .col-m-12 {width: 100%;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    /* For desktop: */
    .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
    .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-3 {width: 25%;}
    .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
    .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
    .col-6 {width: 50%;}
    .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
    .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
    .col-9 {width: 75%;}
    .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
    .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
    .col-12 {width: 100%;}
}

/*Deactive Certain Conditions On Phone*/
@media only screen and (max-width:500px){
    .nav li{
        margin-right:0px;
    }
}
```

I'm hoping someone better at web development can tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You are doing so wrong. first the column size and sec you need something to measure your whole width for column sizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**: Your column sizing is wrong. When your total column number is 12, in order to split columns you must do some math. For instance, when you want to have a main area + a side area, use something like this `col-4` for sidebar and `col-8` for content => 4+8=12 and so on (another example is `col-2` for side and `col-10` for content).

**Second**: If you need white area in both sides you must limit your content to a container that has a fixed width and set `margin: 0 auto` to it. That will align your whole content in the center, as you asked for.

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/7jsxL7km/3/)

CSS (update):

```
.container {width:960px;margin: 0 auto;}
```

HTML (Update):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2 col-m-2 nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">Link2</a></li>
                <li><a href="product.html">Link3</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Link4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-10 col-m-10 content">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**P.S**: These codes are just part of main code that I've updated. Do not copy/paste them. Instead use Jsfiddle (it's complete).

**P.S-2**: You can change `960px` to any size you desire. `100%` for full responsive, `1140px` for modern standard grid size and `960px` for 960 grid size.

Comment: Thanks so much I now understand what I was doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

To remain within your used grid system, you can insert an (almost) empty DIV before the `nav` div which uses the `.col-2` class, therefore spans 2 columns of the grid and will therefore move the 2 + 6 column elements to the horizontal center (leaving 2 empty columns left and 2 empty columns right).

In my fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/grhpatv3/3/ I inserted `<div class="col-2">&nbsp;</div>`

(You'll have to to find similar solutions for the medium size - but that will work better if the sum of all used columns is even, not odd -> see my fiddle)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class to the div that contains the two items you want to center and then display that as flex `display: flex` and set `flex-direction: center`.

Comment: `display:flex`? at least mention browser support.